# lastOp is undefined

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

So, I'm screwing around with creating contracts with another contract and bunch of other stuff.

Here's the code for both:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Nanite{
    bool public Selling = false;
    uint public Price;
    bytes32[] public dna;
    address public owner;

    function Nanite() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
        uint nonce = uint(NaniteFactory(owner).accessNonce());
        for (uint i=0;i<256/32;i++){
            dna.push(keccak256(now + i + nonce));
        }
    }

    function sell(uint newPrice) public{
        if (owner == msg.sender){
            Selling = true;
            Price = newPrice;
        }
    }

    function cancelSell() public{
        if (owner == msg.sender){
            Selling = false;
        }
    }

    function buy() public payable{
        if (msg.value == Price && Selling){
            address oldOwner = owner;
            owner = msg.sender;
            oldOwner.transfer(msg.value);
        } else {
            msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
        }
    }
}


contract NaniteFactory{
    uint nonce;
    address Owner;
    address[] public nanites;
    function NaniteFactory() public{
        // Set the owner - for destruction&withdraw verification
        Owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function accessNonce() public returns(uint){
        uint oldNonce = nonce;
        nonce++;
        return oldNonce;
    }

    function createNanite() public{
        // Create the nanite contract
        address newNanite = new Nanite();
        // Interface with the nanite contract, and sell it for 10 finney
        Nanite(newNanite).sell(10 finney);
        // Add the nanite to 
        nanites.push(newNanite);
    }

    function destroy() public{
        if (msg.sender == Owner){
            selfdestruct(Owner);
        } 
    }
}
```

I create the NaniteFactory contract. No errors.
I call the createNanite method in that contract. No errors.
I retrieve the new nanite's address, it's there.
I interface with the contract that should be on that address, call to nanite.sol:Nanite.dna errored: lastOp is undefined

Anybody got any idea what's going on, because I don't if I'm being honest.

By the way, it's been written in Solidity IDE, and I've also been testing it out there.

EDIT:
So, the WebIDE has been updated, but unfortunately, it has not fixed the bug, still waiting for reports on GitHub (where they asked me to verify if the new version still has the bug)

Comment: I tried you example in remix, it appears to be a bug in remix, you should report in their github repo https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/issues.